# How to access data stored on an account on chain?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

I have stored information in the following account:

```
#[account]
pub struct user{
    name: String,
    age:  u64
}
```

I want to get this information from chain and display it on my frontend using Reactjs.

What are the solana/web3js commands to access data stored in accounts on chain

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Anchor (which I recommend), you can use `fetch` to decode account data easily.

If you're not using Anchor you need to specify the structure and decode it using something like [borsh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/borsh).

Here is an example

```
const schema = new Map([[Test, { kind: 'struct', fields: [['x', 'u8'], ['y', 'u64'], ['z', 'string'], ['q', [3]]] }]]);

const newValue = borsh.deserialize(schema, decoded, buffer);
```

---

[Example I wrote of decoding Metaplex Metadata](https://github.com/vicyyn/MetaplexMetadata-js/blob/main/utils.ts)

Comment: can you guide me about fetch? 
I tried googling it but couldn't find much